# Does ip6tables support tcp-flags?

Tags: ip6tables

I have below command

`ip6tables -A INPUT -m ipv6header --header hop,dst,route,frag,auth,esp,none,prot --tcp-flags ACK SYN`

But getting error as `ip6tables v1.8.4 (legacy): unknown option "--tcp-flags"`

I have tried `--tcp-flags` option with `iptables`, It works fine. But in `ip6tables`, it gives error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

quote from [`man ip6tables`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ip6tables)

> These extensions are loaded if '--protocol tcp' is specified. It provides the following options:

add the argument `--protocol tcp`.

```
ip6tables -A INPUT -m ipv6header --header hop,dst,route,frag,auth,esp,none,prot \
    --protocol tcp --tcp-flags ACK SYN
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the man page, `--tcp-flags` is part of an extension that is loaded if `--protocol tcp` is specified. Your command line does not seem to specify `--protocol tcp`, hence the extension is not present and the option is not available.